# Dibujar el rango de una linea de matplotlib con un color diferente PYTHON

Tags: python

Estoy intentando realizar un gráfico de línea en matplotlib o seaborn que tenga un rango específico de esa línea en un color diferente, pero no consigo encontrar la solución. El rango va de '2018-09' a '2021-09' y me gustaría que la línea durante unos meses concretos sea de un color distinto. Lo he intentado de la siguiente manera pero no lo consigo, y al ser algo nuevo en Python tampoco se me ocurren muchas alternativas posibles. Ojalá alguno podáis echarme una mano.

```
clrs = ['yellow' if (x in rango) else 'red' for x in g_nuevo['time']] 
sns.lineplot(ax = ax, x = 'time', y = 'grade', data =g_nuevo, palette = clrs)
```

Haciéndolo con seaborn no me da ningún error, pero no me aparece ningún cambio en el gráfico. Haciéndolo con matplotlib este es el error que me da:

```
ValueError: ['yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow',, 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', ..., 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red'] is not a valid value for color
```

Comment: Yo haría dos lineplot, cada uno de un color, seleccionando un slice diferente de los datos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @albulafia. Ha funcionado correctamente.